# Office 2013 interop 14

Tags: c#, excel

I have developed some applications that create Excel Spreadsheets.  They have bee runnng fine on a windows 2003 Serve for some years.  We recently upgrade our servers to Windows 2008 r2.  Now the application runs fine from a command prompt, but fails when run as a scheduled task.  Specifically, it fails, throwing an exception when setting sheets in new workbook:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xl.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
```

and more importantly when saving the workbook:

```
workbook.Close(true, @"\\.....\" + name + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xlsx", Missing.Value);
```

any I ideas?

Comment: and this exception is...?

Comment: *throwing an exception* is useful information only when you also include information on the exception itself.